System of non-linear differential equations, $\dot{\vec{\theta}} = K^{-1} \hat{J}^{T} \vec{h}$
Suppose I have following system $\hat{J} \dot{\vec{\theta}} = \vec{h}$ with $\hat{J}$ is a function of $\theta$. I want to solve $\vec{\theta}$.
Naively, one starts with the following construction. Let $K = \hat{J}^{T} \hat{J}$ where $T$ denote the transpose. Then $K$ have inverse $K^{-1}$, so we have
\begin{align}
\dot{\vec{\theta}} = K^{-1} \hat{J}^{T} \vec{h}
\end{align}
with additional $\hat{J} K^{-1} \hat{J}^{T}=1$.(This is due to the fact that $\hat{J}$ may not have inverse)
Is there any method/reference/books to solve this system (even in numerics)? Since $\hat{J}$ contains $\theta$, $K$ also have $\theta$, so $K^{-1} \hat{J}^T$ is function of $\theta$ and so it seems (without explicit expression for $\hat{J}$) hard to solve $\theta$.
I want to know where there are some nice ways to handle this problem.

To be more clear, my assumption of $\hat{J}$ is bounded. Without applying numerics, I want to know whether the solution exists, converges or not.

Beside numerical analysis, I want to find some simple example for this kinds of non-linear system of differential equations, and understand some basic techniques at least for the simple case.

You could try to solve it numerically with gradient descent on f(theta) = |Jhat.theta - h|, or f^2 if that's easier to compute. There's no guarantee it would always converge on a solution though.

@SimonGoater, How one can find the convergence on this type of solution? can you introduce me some methods? (For my background on the analysis, I almost forgot many basic analysis techniques relating with existence and convergence of solution)

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent. I think there are some packages which can do it, but if you do it yourself, you need to pick an arbitrary starting point as best you can, calculate the gradient of f there, then move a small step in the opposite direction and you should get a lower value for f there. Keep doing that until f is zero, and you have a solution. It will work best if you calculate the derivatives yourself. I think packages often do it numerically which can introduce a lot of error.
